# The output is always the same even if the algorithm works C/C++

Tags: c++, c, string

I've got this snippet of code that checks for the biggest set of numbers in a formatted file and even if the algorithm works, getting the position of the said values, the output is always the last read row. What is happening?

```
int main() {
int n, north_key, east_key;
char *identity, *time, *eastIdentity, *eastTime, *northIdentity, *northTime;
float latitude, longitude, max_east = MIN, max_north = MIN;
input = fopen("level2-1.in", "r");
fscanf(input, "%d", &n);
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    char line[MAX];
    fgets(line, MAX, input);  
    identity = strtok(line, ","); 
    time = strtok(NULL, ",");

    char *aux = strtok(NULL, ",");
    latitude = std::atof(aux);
    aux = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    longitude = std::atof(aux);

    if(max_north < latitude) {
        max_north     = latitude;
        north_key     = i;
        northIdentity = identity;
        northTime     = time;
     }

    if(max_east < longitude) {
        max_east      = longitude;
        east_key      = i;
        eastIdentity  = identity;
        eastTime      = time;
    }
    printf("%d, %d\n", north_key, east_key);
}
printf("%s,%s, %s,%s\n", northIdentity, northTime, eastIdentity, eastTime);
fclose(input);
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Run your program in a debugger.

Comment: This is C not C++. Oh wait no that single `std::atof` makes it C++.

Comment: If you don't get the expected output, how can the algorithm be working?

Comment: @user4581301 well, the north_key and east_key variables are actually correct 100% of cases. the only problem is that the printed strings are always the last read line from the file

Answer (score 1):

The outputs are all pointers to segments of `line`, and `line` is overwritten by every iteration. Further, `line` has gone out of scope by the time the outputs are printed. Accessing invalid memory results in [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

The outputs must be preserved by copying them to their own storage.

Strongly consider using `std::string`s (and possibly `string`s all the way through with a `std::istringstream` in place of `strtok`).

Notes:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```

looks like it may read one past the end. `i <= n` allows  `i` to reach `n` (Range is [0, n]) for a total of `n+1` iterations. You probably want `i < n`.

Comment: Since the OP tagged his question as "c++" instead of "c", it was appropriate for the answerer to recommend using `std::string`. However, I suspect that the OP may be looking for a C-style solution. If that is the case, then he should change the tag to "c".

Comment: is there any way to store the desired strings even if they keep changing? also, i know about the i to n issue, i used it this way to quickly go around the fact that the program wasn't reading my last line from the file. it's by no means perfect, but it does it's job of helping me debug the program

Comment: @Bozgorian Allocate storage for the output variables. Write the current values into that storage  when you find a new max. Easy as pie with `std::string`. Use arrays and `strcpy` if you can't use `std::string`.